# Item Descriptor Inheritance in ATG for "contactInfo"

Tags: atg

I am trying to inherit the "contactInfo" item and create a new item descriptor.. Something like this as given below..

```
<item-descriptor name="testContactInfo" super-type="contactInfo">
    <table name="test_contact_info" type="auxiliary" id-column-name="contact_id" shared-table-sequence="1">
        <property name="fixedlinenumber" column-name="fixed_line_num" data-type="string"/>
    </table>
</item-descriptor>
```

I get the following error when i start the server.

```
14:19:52,856 ERROR [ProfileAdapterRepository] Error parsing template: atg.repository.RepositoryException: Your item-descriptor definition for testContactInfo has super-type contactInfo but no sub-type attribute.
```

what am i doing wrong here? I have kept the definition in userProfile.xml

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark the right answer. If it has not, please ask further questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: are you actually looking to create a subtype of the contactInfo item descriptor - that is to say, are you expecting there to be some items in your system of type contactInfo and some items of type testContactInfo - or are you just looking to add a custom property to the existing contactInfo item descriptor?

If you are actually trying to create a subtype of contactInfo, then you need to modify the descriptor of contactInfo to tell it how to differentiate between items of type contactInfo and items of type testContactInfo. You will need to add a property, say contactType, to contactInfo and set the sub-type-property attribute

```
<item-descriptor name="contactInfo" sub-type-property="contactType" ...>
  ...
  <property name="contactType" data-type="enumerated">
    <option value="standard"/>
    <option value="test"/>
  </property>
  ...
</item-descriptor>
```

and then you can subtype it

```
<item-descriptor name="testContactInfo" super-type="contactInfo" sub-type-value="test">
  ...
</item-descriptor>
```

If, however, you are just looking to add a custom property to it, you can very well add to the existing definition. You do not need to subtype to extend an out-of-the-box item. For example

```
<item-descriptor name="contactInfo">
  <table name="test_contact_info" type="auxiliary" id-column-name="contact_id" shared-table-sequence="1">
    <property name="fixedlinenumber" column-name="fixed_line_num" data-type="string"/>
  </table>
</item-descriptor>
```

will result in a new property called fixedlinenumber added to the standard contactInfo item.

Answer (score 0):

Item-descriptor inheritance can be done in two ways. You can:-

1. Add new properties for existing item-descriptor.
   Here you can add many properties to an existing item-descriptor. This can be out of the box, or your custom repository.

For example, you can have a employeeId property to contactInfo item-descriptor, which would be available for all contactInfo items.

2. Create a sub-type of an item-descriptor.
   This is generally used to have distinctive properties for a particular item-descriptor.

For example, in your contactInfo type, you can have a "employeeContactInfo" wherein you want to store an extra employee id, and you can have a "employeeId" only for this type.

So, it basically depends on your requirements. You can see some details on this website.. nice tutorials:-

http://learnoracleatg.blogspot.in/2014/11/art203-how-to-extend-out-of-box-non.html
and
http://learnoracleatg.blogspot.in/2014/12/art204-how-to-add-new-item-descriptor.html